# Shadow for labels in vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

It seems possible to set a shadow for nodes and edges, but is it also possible to specify a (drop)shadow for label texts in vis.js? I cannot find any properties for it in the documents, but perhaps it's possible with some trick?